# Labview or a similar software in Ubuntu Studio

Tags: software-recommendation

I have made a speech recognition system using HTK in Ubuntu Studio, and now I want to simulate that system using something similar to LabView. I know that Labview isn't supported on Ubuntu, so I want to know if theres another option to make a graphic simulation. Does someone know how can I make this simulation using Ubuntu Studio?

Answer (score 1):

> **MyOpenLab**

The website [myopenlab.de](https://myopenlab.de) is in German but the latest version of the software is in English.

Source: [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_is_the_best_alternative_to_Labview_open_source)

It seems to have builds for linux and requires Java.